# Html.RenderAction fails in page after RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page "ViewUser". with this structure

```
//display something about the user
@{Html.RenderAction("UpdateUser", new { UserId = @Model.UserId });}
//display some more stuff
```

In the controller method for UpdateUser I have

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int UserId){//populate form vars
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateUser(User u)//
// code to update the user
return RedirectToAction("ViewUser", new { User = u.UserId });
```

When I open the page it works fine I see my user data and the date in the UpdateUser form.
However when I update the user data and redirect to the ViewUser page from UpdateUser I get
"Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."

but opening the page manually again show that the update was successful.
As far as I understand the browser should be performing a new GET for everything so I don't understand why it works for a manual refresh but not when UpdateUser returns the redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite clear:

```
Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
```

When you call an action directly (not as a child action) it's responsibel for deciding what it returns to the browser. So it can decide to return a Redirect.

However, if this action is invoked as a child action, there is already a main Action which has decided what to return to the browser, and is asking this child action to render additional HTML. So, if the child action returns something different, as a Redirect, it fails.

See this, [ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Invokes a child action method and renders the result inline in the parent view.

A redirect, or anything that is not HTML (a View / PartialView result) can't be rendered inside the parent view.

You could simulate a "redirect" from a child action including an script that redirects the page, by including this JavaScript on it ([How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)):

```
window.location.replace('@Url.Action(...)');
```

Anyway you'd rather do it from the main view, by using the same logic that you're using on the partial to decide to make the redirect.

Comment: Thanks JotaBe. So how can I return the ViewUser as a non-Child action? Is there anything wrong with this pattern it seems very natural to me?